# Why am I getting notification only for the built-in actions like REPLY?

Tags: python, notifications, subscription, google-glass, mirror

I can't find a solution to my problem.
When I use the build-in actions like REPLY everything works great. I am getting a callback to my URL and I can handle it.

However, if I send CUSTOM action with my own menu items, The card is arriving perfectly, but when I choose some option, nothing happens. 
I examined the logs and I am certain no "notify" event is coming.

Do I need to do something special for the custom events?

This is the card I'm sending:

```
body = {
        'creator': {
            'displayName': 'creator:',
            'id': 'creator_id',         
        },
        'text': 'HELLO :)',
        'title': 'This is the title:)',
        'notification': {'level': 'DEFAULT'},
        'menuItems': [ {
            "action": "CUSTOM",
            "id": "OPT_1",
            'state' : 'DEFAULT',
            "values": [{
                "displayName": "OPT_1",
                "iconUrl": [util.get_full_url(self, '/static/images/python.png')],
            }]
            },
            {
            "action": "CUSTOM",
            "id": "OPT_2",
            "values": [{
                "displayName": "OPT_2",
                "iconUrl": [util.get_full_url(self, '/static/images/python.png')],
            }]
            }
        ]
    }
```

```
self.mirror_service.timeline().insert(body=body).execute()
```

Comment: Do you mean google glass? The syntax of the last line looks a little like python if that is true please add this tag.

Comment: I wrote it in python, i'm not sure If it matters.. Anyhow added the tag, thanks

Comment: couple of suggestions , check the JSON format that is being sent to the server and check the logs on your server if the requests are getting rejected . so if you are using apache look at error.log